# Does the experience required to level up ever plateau?

Tags: league-of-legends

In patch 7.22, League of Legends implemented a leveling system to replace their previous system that capped the level at 30. With this new system, there is no level cap and the player's account level will continue infinitely.

When attempting to estimate the speed at which a player levels up, according to the [League of Legends Wikia](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Experience_(summoner)),

> Estimating the required time to level up can be done by taking one's level and noting its position beyond a multiple of 25 (except for the first two progressions: 1 to 30, and 31 to 50). Example: Leveling from 51 to 52 is faster than leveling 74 to 75, but also quicker than a player at level 49, since you're positioned at the very first level of the count (51 to 75).

However, I have been unable to find any site that references any sort of experience required plateau that a player may reach when leveling up their account. **So my question is, is there any sort of plateau that a player will reach, or will the experience required to level up a player's account just increase infinitely?**

---

*Edit*: It was brought up to me that the [Leveling Up section](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Experience_(summoner)#Leveling_up) in the Wikia linked earlier also contains a graph that includes the XP needed to reach the next level. Unfortunately, once the higher levels are reached in the graph, the XP needed just changes to question marks. So it may be the case that nobody knows for sure.

Comment: I'm 95% sure it caps at level 150, I think I saw a Rioter mention that somewhere. I'll go do some research, see if I can find it again.

Comment: Per the graph in the Leveling Up section of the League of Legends Wikia, it is already known that the levels go up infinitely.
http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Experience_(summoner)#Leveling_up

Comment: I was half-right... it used to plateau at 150, now it's 50. See my answer for details.

Comment: My apologies, I misunderstood your initial comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The required experience needed per level goes through a "staircase effect" depending on where your progress to the next milestone level is.

[image: Exp needed to level up]

In the above graph, the blue line represent the leveling curve as initially released during the preseason, and the orange line is the updated (current) leveling curve. As you can see, in the old system the staircase gradually moved higher and higher until about level 150, where the "staircase of difficulty" for leveling up plateaued. In the new system, the staircase plateaus much earlier, at level 50.

[Source](https://boards.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/developer-corner/hAaYMrEs-leveling-and-rewards-early-impressions-and-adjustments) (Check section: "The 30-and-beyond leveling curve")

Answer (score 0):

Every 25 levels you accomplish, you will receive a glorius champion shard.
After this, your Required EXP to Level-UP (Req.XP) will increase every level.

For example:
Lvl 50 - 51 (Req.XP 2500)
Lvl 51 - 52 (Req.XP 2610)
Lvl 53 - 54 (Req.XP 2780)
Lvl 74 - 75 (Req.XP 3790)
So you need more Req.XP until you hit another 50th level.

As soon as you hit level 75, the Req.XP will restart at a lower amount

for example:
Lvl 74 - 75 (Req.XP 3790)
Lvl 75 - 76 (Req.XP 2700)
Lvl 76 - 77 (Req.XP 2840)

And if there is a plateau? That is yet to find out, or needs to be developed yet by their dev team.

Comment: There is a plateau. If you take a look at my answer, you can see that the "staircase effect" that you're describing stops getting higher once you reach level 50. The graph comes directly from a Riot Games employee.

Comment: yes, it does get higher. But resets every 50 levels. Thats what i was saying :)